# How to get elements of an internal class element?

Tags: html, css

I am working on making a collapsible element

I want to access

```html
<div id="class1">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="#" >link 1</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#" >link 2</a></li>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li> <a href="#" >link 1-1</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#" >link 1-2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
```

I want to change the color of linki 1-1 when the link 2 is active or hide it when the link 2 is inactive.

Hope I am being clear here.

Comment: Have you tried jQuery UI accordion: https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: this might help you http://jsfiddle.net/tovic/CzE3q/

Comment: I would suggest changing your markup as it is currently invalid. You'll want to nest `.submenu` in link 2's `li`. This will also make it easier to achieve the result you are after.

Comment: Yes, this is invalid HTML..a `ul`cannot be a direct child of another `ul`. It's really not clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Just created a rough mockup for achieving the desired result. Please note there are many ways of achieving and this is only a way

```js
$("#drop").click(function() {
  $(".item").toggle("active")
})
```

```css
.active {
  display: block;
 
}
.item {
  display: none
}
.item a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="class1">
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="#">link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#" id="drop">link 2</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li class="item"> <a href="#">link 1-1</a>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">link 1-2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```